# The way to connect to SQL Server using unix bash scripts

Tags: sql-server, shell, unix, odbc

I have seen a lot of links on the internet regarding this but I am in a little fix as to how can we connect to a SQL Server database and insert some records to it using a shell script.

I want to be able to create a function which accepts the values for the row, creates an sql statement and then executes it to insert data into the SQL Server Database. I know that there is Microsoft ODBC for this but I am not sure as to how we can create the said function with it.

Comment: So what have you done so far, and what isn't working? You've told us what you want to do, but not asked a question.

Comment: I have seen that we can connect to the SQL Server using odbc.ini, I want to know how can I create a function that connects to the SQL server according to the Database name, etc that I define and then can insert the values that I want into the DB

Comment: Using Bash, Powershell, a different scripting or executable language (i.e. Python).

Comment: So you are suggesting, I create the function in some other language and just call it in the script? Is there a direct way to do it in the script itself?

Comment: What script? You haven't shown us that, which is why I asked *"So what have you done so far, and what isn't working?"*

Comment: I am not sure how to write it, I understand that we are supposed to do something before we ask question here but in this case I am not even able to find a starting point thus was asking for suggestions, my aim as I said is to create a .sh script function to insert values to a sql server db, can you point me to an example that can help me achieve that?

Comment: Asking for off site resources isn't what Stack Overflow is for. If you want to find tutorials, then that's what your favourite search engine is for. I suggest searching something like "Create ODBC connection is bash shell script"

Comment: I searched that and mostly hit tutorials for powershell scripts, anyways thanks for your inputs I think I will try the python way in case nothing works

Comment: With bash, you could invoke the `sqlcmd` utility to run T-SQL scripts. But a different scripting language, or a hybrid solution, is more robust.

Comment: What you need is a SQL Server client for your operating system, if it exists!  This will provide you with command line utilities and libraries required to connect to and run queries on SQL Server.  Using these command line utilities in a script is then trivial, since these are commands like any other.  A shell is just a sequence of commands, so you do not require any library, ODBC, ...  These go with code (ex. C, C++) or JDBC for Java.  Python also has modules for this (through pip install probably).

Comment: A big of searching got me this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15  there are many other links available on the web.

Comment: I know of the high level language based solutions, I wanted to know if on UBUNTU after installing the driver, we can directly make entries from the Unix Bash .sh script without using the sqlcmd